# Visualization of my Finite Element Analysis results

Tags: data-visualization

I have developed a finite element solver using c++ to solve 3D quasi-static problem. I am trying to find a way to visualize my result, like deformed geometry, stress field and strain field. I know ParaView can do this job but it looks like extra codes are needed to pass my data into ParaView and this process seems to be nontrivial. So is there any convenient way to visualize those results? Or any existing codes to help me to pass my data into ParaView?